# How to return result from an event callback in a hapijs route handler (version 17+)

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

In the following route, I want to get the number of keys deleted from redis by using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)'`scanStream` method. If I code it like the following I would always get `{ len: null }` in the response because the return statement doesn't wait for `stream.on` to finish. I am pulling out my hair but can't find a solution. Advice?

```js
{
  route: '/some/path/{somekey}',
  handler: (request, h) => {
    // redis is an ioredis instance
    const { redis, params } = request
    const stream = redis.scanStream({
      match: `someprefix:${params.somekey}-*`
    })
    let len = null
    stream.on('data', async keys => {
      len = keys.length
      console.log(`removing ${keys}`)
      if (len > 0) {
        const pipeline = client.pipeline()
        keys.forEach(key => pipeline.del(key))
        await pipeline.exec()
      }
    })
    return { len }
  }
}
```

Comment: but you can easily separate the `stream.on` into it's own function and return a promise ... now you can `await` for the `stream.on`

Comment: @balexandre that should work. However I found out a different way to do it, please see my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, instead of

```
return { len }
```

do

```
return new Promise(resolve => stream.on('end', () => resolve({ len })))
```

There might be cleaner solutions out there but this seems to get the work done for now.